# What is the best way to create a substitution cipher to map a string of normal alphabet to a string of jumbled alphabet, to encrypt a message?

Tags: java, encryption, substitution, alphabet

```
public static String EncodeString() { 
    String plaintext = "Hello Jon";
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String Substituion = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
    
    for(int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<alphabet.length(); j++){
            if(plaintext[i]==alphabet[j]) {
                //not sure what to do here because the code above is giving an error
            }
            
        }

    }
```

For example "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" is the normal alphabet, jumbled alphabet is "zyxwutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba" and the string message is "Hi Jon". So the message should be encrypted according to the jumbled alphabet, however the alphabet can be entered by the user meaning it will be different everytime.

I know I can either use arrays, for loops or hashmaps, but which is the most effective?

Above is the code that I am trying at the moment but I am a bit stuck, I know I'm doing something wrong but not sure what. Also it should return an encrypted string that is plaintext but encrypted, I haven't added that yet.

Comment: I would use extra parameter "password" to do predictable permutation of the original alphabet string (to make it fool-proof) and make a hashmap on the fly which would map input letter of original alphabet into output letter of generated alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is giving an error because you are trying to use `plaintext` and `alpabet` as Arrays, but they are not Arrays. So `plaintext[int]` can't work. Instead, I would use `String.charAt(int)`. This allows you to check if two **characters** are equal without using Arrrays. I think, this works easier through the jumbled alphabet can be changed by the user. The code would then be:

```
public static String EncodeString() { 
    String plaintext = "Hello Jon";
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "; //space added
    String substitution = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba ";
    String encrypted_message = "";

for(int i=0; i<plaintext.length(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<alphabet.length(); j++){
        if(plaintext.charAt(i)==alphabet.charAt(j)) {
            encrypted_message += Substitution.charAt(j); //This adds the right character of the jumbled aplhabet to the encrypted message
        }
        }
    }
    return encrypted_message; //returns the encrypted message
}
```

Now, you should know that this program only works with the lower case letters from a to z and the space. To avoid this you can either add all uppercase chracters to the two alphabets, or use `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel here. Just use the **java.util.Base64** class. Although not overly secure, it will still be far superior towards security than what you are attempting to utilize and....far easier to code and use:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String message = "\nWhat is your name?\nYour Address?\nYour Phone Number?";  
        System.out.println("Original Message: --> " + message);
        String encodedMessage = encode(message);
        System.out.println("Encoded Message:  --> " + encodedMessage);
        System.out.println("Decoded Message:  --> " + decode(encodedMessage));   
    }

    public static String encode(String inputString) {
        // Getting MIME encoder 
        java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder();  
        // Encode supplied String and return.
        return encoder.encodeToString(inputString.getBytes());  
    }
    
    public static String decode(String encodedString) {
        // Getting MIME Decoder 
        java.util.Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder();  
        // Decode supplied Encoded String and return.
        return new String(decoder.decode(encodedString));  
    }

}
```

Console output will be:

```
Original Message: --> 
What is your name?
Your Address?
Your Phone Number?
Encoded Message:  --> CldoYXQgaXMgeW91ciBuYW1lPwpZb3VyIEFkZHJlc3M/CllvdXIgUGhvbmUgTnVtYmVyPw==
Decoded Message:  --> 
What is your name?
Your Address?
Your Phone Number?
```